# Filling an array with json in AngularJS service

Tags: angularjs

In my angularjs service I want an array to be filled as follows:

```
var results = [
  {id: 1, name: 'John'},
  {id: 2, name: 'Jane}
]
```

I want to do this by calling an API. So far I have written this:

```
function getDataFromAPI() {
  $http.get('foo.com/bar.json').then(function(data){
    console.log( data.data.employees);
  });
}

var results = getDataFromAPI();
```

When I call `results`, in my chrome dev tools it will display the results from the json file, but I don't know how to populate the `results` array.

How can I fill the array?

Answer (score 1):

`$http.get` (and many other functions in Angular) returns a [promise](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/).

```
var results;
function getDataFromAPI() {
    return $http.get('foo.com/bar.json');
}

getDAtaFromAPI().then(function(data) {
    results = data;
});
```